# PostgreSQL configs are ignored

Tags: configuration, postgresql, make

I have a custom postgresql build, that shows the following output on `pg_config`

```
BINDIR = /var/buildout.webstacks.xwiki/bin
DOCDIR = /var/buildout.webstacks.xwiki/share/doc/postgresql
HTMLDIR = /var/buildout.webstacks.xwiki/share/doc/postgresql
INCLUDEDIR = /var/buildout.webstacks.xwiki/include
PKGINCLUDEDIR = /var/buildout.webstacks.xwiki/include/postgresql
INCLUDEDIR-SERVER = /var/buildout.webstacks.xwiki/include/postgresql/server
LIBDIR = /var/buildout.webstacks.xwiki/lib
PKGLIBDIR = /var/buildout.webstacks.xwiki/lib/postgresql
LOCALEDIR = /var/buildout.webstacks.xwiki/share/locale
MANDIR = /var/buildout.webstacks.xwiki/share/man
SHAREDIR = /var/buildout.webstacks.xwiki/share/postgresql
SYSCONFDIR = /var/buildout.webstacks.xwiki/etc/postgresql
PGXS = /var/buildout.webstacks.xwiki/lib/postgresql/pgxs/src/makefiles/pgxs.mk
CONFIGURE = '--prefix=/var/buildout.webstacks.xwiki' '--sysconfdir=/var/buildout.webstacks.xwiki/etc'
CC = gcc
CPPFLAGS = -D_GNU_SOURCE
CFLAGS = -O2 -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wendif-labels -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv
CFLAGS_SL = -fpic
LDFLAGS = -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,-rpath,'/var/buildout.webstacks.xwiki/lib'
LDFLAGS_SL = 
LIBS = -lpgport -lz -lreadline -lcrypt -ldl -lm 
VERSION = PostgreSQL 8.4.9
```

The config files should be in `/var/buildout.webstacks.xwiki/etc/postgresql`.

But when I add or edit config files in that path, they get ignored. Instead postgres uses files in the data-directory, created during `initdb`.

How can I make postgres use my configs (in addition), according to my `./configure` command.

Comment: Have never done that, but check permissions. Log in with user `postgres` from root and try to read files from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be only one way to move  `postgresql.conf` out of the `data-directory. During server startup.

From the docs:

> **config_file** (string) Specifies the main server configuration file (customarily called postgresql.conf). **This parameter can only be set on the postgres command line**.

Inside `postgresql.conf` directives as:

```
hba_file='/var/buildout.webstacks.davical/etc/postgresql/pg_hba.conf'       
ident_file = '/var/buildout.webstacks.davical/etc/postgresql/pg_ident'
```

can be used to refer to `pg_hba.conf` and `pg_ident.conf`.

See also: [PostgreSQL documentation](http://config_file%20(string)%20%20%20%20%20%20Specifies%20the%20main%20server%20configuration%20file%20(customarily%20called%20postgresql.conf).%20This%20parameter%20can%20only%20be%20set%20on%20the%20postgres%20command%20line.)